# Drupal places a <br> after text automatically?

Tags: input-formats

I have the below code, however when I place it within Drupal 6, Drupal places a 
 after the text 'Coordinator', see second code insert for the firebug info. I am not sure where this 
 is coming from? but it would be useful to remove as it means I have a text description, and the selection boxis on the line below. While all my other input box are inline with their descriptions.

```
Coordinator:<?php 
 //Drop Down Select
 $sql = "SELECT user_id, concat (user_firstname,' ', user_surname) as username  FROM   user_tbl WHERE coordinator='True'";
    $result = pg_query($sql);
         echo "<select name='user_id'>";
       while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo  "<option value='" . $row['user_id'] . " '>" . $row['username'] ."</option>";
 }
         echo "</select>";
?>
```

Second Code

```
<p>
Coordinator:
<br>
<select name="user_id">
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP filter / HTML filter was to blame with the auto break text

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see this problem before but maybe try to rewrite code above as follows:

```
<?php 
//Drop Down Select
$sql = "SELECT user_id, concat (user_firstname,' ', user_surname) as username                       FROM   user_tbl WHERE coordinator='True'";
    $result = pg_query($sql);
         echo "Coordinator:<select name='user_id'>";
       while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo  "<option value='" . $row['user_id'] . " '>" . $row['username']     ."</option>";
 }
         echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: I have tried that, but the same issue. Obviously somewhere there is some code that is inserting a <br>. But it is strange that it is only doing it to PHP select boxes, and not standard form inputs.

Comment: Maybe you have some custom javascript which adds that <br>? Try to disable javascript in browser and reload the page. If it's not the case it must be some hook implemented which adds this <br>